# Why do I need a shower faucet cartridge?

Tags: water, faucet

What's it for?

Will the shower work without one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A shower faucet cartridge is a type of valve. It's the part that a single handle faucet is moving inside the plumbing fixture to adjust the flow and temperature. They tend to have o-rings and other parts that fail over time, which can result in a variety of issues, including leaks, and the hot and cold water mixing when they shouldn't, even when the fixture is turned off.

[image: faucet assembly]

Comment: A shower cartridge is like a kitchen faucet

Comment: You answered the "*What's it for?*" part. As for "*Will the shower work without one?*". Yes, but you won't be able to change the temperature of the water, or turn it off.

Comment: @Tester101 - Not sure if I would call that *working*.. lol